# Is the OAuth2 implicit flow always 3-legged?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm setting up a web service with OAuth2 authorization/authentication. If I understand correctly, the **implicit flow** should be used for native desktop apps, because decompilation and other processes could potentially expose the client secret.

Implicit flow requires a valid redirect URI, but I don't understand how these should be used. I am **not** looking for 3-legged authentication through a facebook app or something, but 2-legged with direct access to my own web services. Like the Facebook and Twitter apps themselves do.

My question is: is OAuth2 implicit flow always 3-legged? And if so, how do Facebook and Twitter's apps ensure that the client secret isn't leaked? If they *are* using implicit flow, how does their redirecting scheme work?

Comment: Come one, really no one knows how this is done?

Comment: Maybe they are using the `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` for their own clients.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question today and couldn't find any answers or posts either.

So what I have discovered so far:

1) Yes, implicit grant flow always consists of two/three steps (depending on how you count):

- User is redirected to the authorisation page;
- User confirms he grants access to this app;
- User is redirected back to the consumer app, access token is passed as a hash fragment parameter.

2) Client secret is not used at all with implicit grant flow. It wouldn't make sense anyway - it would be in the plain sight. However, there are still some security measures: implicit grant usually requires a pre-approved redirect URL, so only specified trusted URL will ever get an access token.

3) Yes, I also noticed that even though Facebook/Twitter use OAuth2 heavily, you won't see these steps when you use their own web application. I have several suspicions:

- They may not use OAuth2 for their own web apps at all;
- They may pass the token using their own, non-documented flow;
- They may pre-authorize their own apps so that authorization step is skipped.

I personally chose the latter option for my application. I created a list of internal applications that don't require explicit approval from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect-URI is necessary because the service provider needs to redirect back to your application after the login/user-consent. In case of the desktop application, you will probably open a browser for the login/user-consent and need to get the authorization code or access token back into your desktop application.

Basically there are 3 ways to do this: [Using OAuth 2 with desktop c# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930226/using-oauth-2-with-desktop-c-sharp-application/)

Google nicely describes the problematic and available options:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: Interesting! So the facebook/twitter apps probably use a custom callback URI scheme?