# Github authentication without backend React/Redux/Webpack

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, redux, react-router

I have a frontend React app with Redux and React-Router. I need to create an authentication with Github account. The user should click 'Login with Github', accept authorization and user data should be saved into the Redux store. The problem is that I don't have any backend and I shouldn't use any backend for this app. Is it even possible to use OAuth in frontend only React app or do I have to use a token based Github auth where used is pasting the token with username and the Github API call is just checking if username is correct (the only solution I was able to find).
I used OAuth before but only with backends and using complete libs for that.
The app itself is also making calls to Github search API using id/secret.
Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268175/is-it-possible-to-use-oauth-2-0-without-a-redirect-server

Comment: How is your app making API calls to Github using client_id/client_secret with no backend?

Comment: Just axios requests