# Receive Oauth2 Authorization code from redirected URI

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, redirect

So I wanted to learn about the process of OAuth2 Authentication and decided the best way to do so would be to code the process. So using the Google Sheets API I am able to get the authentication code and redeem it for a token and then access the Sheets methods for posting and such, my only issue is the user has to copy and paste the authentication code to get the token.

So my question is how can I get the authentication code if I use localhost as the redirect uri in C# or am I better off just forgetting trying to do this without using Google's .net Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer over at [Is it possible to use OAuth 2.0 without a redirect server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268175/is-it-possible-to-use-oauth-2-0-without-a-redirect-server) It is the last answer on the page, and it does retrieve the authorization code from the URL.